# Illustrator opacity rendering on artboard vs. white objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency

I recently stumbled on something curious: the white of the artboard and the white of white objects in Illustrator act quite vastly differently on translucent objects on top of them. For example, this is a 30% black square partially eclipsing a 100% opacity white square on the bottom right corner (boundaries shown by the red markers, the rest is artboard):

[image]

Although an intruiging and sometimes helpful feature, I am also concerned about how this will affect my ability to the judge colour and tone of exported translucent images. I am also assuming the lighter tone is a more accurate representation of the final output? What is this feature called, and can I toggle it?

Comment: Do: **View -> Show Transparency Grid**, you can recolor the grid from prefs so you can more easily see white.

Comment: @joojaa It's not the inability to see white against the artboard I am concerned about, but rather the difference in the tone of translucent colors on top of artboard vs. translucent colors on top of white objects. Often, I still find it useful to have a white background to see how the final image will render.

Comment: Ah, turn **View -> Proof Colors** on, still seeing the effect?

Comment: Anyway this is a feature of cmyk color blending. If you do this in rgb mode you shouldn't see anything.

Comment: @joojaa Ah, that's what it is: using RGB space made them uniform. Thanks!